# Azure DevOps - disable pipeline with CI trigger on a specific day of week

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have several pipelines in Azure DevOps that have a Continuous Integration build trigger - After each change on the `dev` branch the build is started, and after that the code is released to the `DEV` environment.

The business need we have is to **not** have automatic deployments to dev on Fridays, while having them on all other days of the week.

We can disable CI trigger manually every Friday in the morning and turn it on in the evening, but can it be automated somehow in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rather won't be able to achieve this using the same pipeline. But what you can do is create another pipeline with scheduled trigger and then update your original build definition using REST API.

[Here you have definition of this call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0
```

I checked in network tab and what you have to se is `queueStatus` where:

- `0` means - `enabled`
- `1` means - `paused`
- `2` means - `disabled`

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#definitionqueuestatus) you have better explanation what these statuses means:

[image]

Calling REST API from pipeline is pretty straightforward as we have `System.AccessToken` available which enable you such operations.

Here is an example (I used there different endpoint but rules are the same):

```yaml
- task: PowerShell@2
  name: ConditionalStep
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "I'm here"
      Write-Host ('$(SomeVariable)' -eq 'Stop')
      if ('$(SomeVariable)' -eq 'Stop') {
        $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/thecodemanual/DevOps Manual/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.BuildId)?api-version=5.1"

        $json = @{status="Cancelling"} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

        $build = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Patch -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $json

        Write-Host $build
      }
      Write-Host "And now here!"
    pwsh: true
```

in your case I would recommend to make first call to get definition of the pipeline, modify `queueStatus` and send it back.

Of course you need to check if your pipeline runs on Friday/Saturday and then set `2` and on Monday morning set it to `0` (or create to separate pipelines).