# Disable Continuous Integration on Pipeline using the Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the pipeline REST endpoint documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2) to create my pipelines and associate them with a YAML file. On some of my pipelines I want to have continuous integration disabled. On the DevOps portal you can do that here:

[image]

I would like to automate this as part of my process but I do not see anything in the official documentation.

I have tried passing in what I see the portal doing when I inspect the payloads being sent from the UI by adding an empty triggers array to the configuration property in my payload when calling the **Pipelines - Create** endpoint but this seems to be ignored.:

```
"triggers":[]
```

Here is a complete payload example:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "variables": {
      "VARIABLE_NAME": {
        "isSecret": false,
        "value": "Value"
      }
    },
    "type": "yaml",
    "path": "azure-pipelines.yml",
    "repository": {
      "id": "repo-id",
      "type": "azureReposGit",
      "name": "repo-name"
    },
    "triggers": []
  },
  "name": "Production"
}
```

Is there a way to override/disable the CI settings on my YAML file through the REST API or is this only something that can be achieved through the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65232113/azure-devops-disable-pipeline-with-ci-trigger-on-a-specific-day-of-week) by Krzysztof Madej you need to use **Update Definition API** and ***set the value of queueStatus as Disabled.*** Or use **Create Definiton API** and set the value of ***queueStatus as Disabled.***
***Definiton API reference-***
[Definitions - REST API (Azure DevOps Build) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

**As Create/Get Pipeline API does not contain queueStatus value in the output,** Refer below :-

**Powershell code: -**

API Reference- [Pipelines - Get - REST API (Azure DevOps Pipelines) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2)

```
$PAT = "xxxxxxxxxa4gzoia"
$OrgName = "sid24desai0738"
$ProjectName = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "7.0"

# Retrieve pipelines information
$pipelines = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$OrgName/$ProjectName/_apis/pipelines/257?api-version=7.1-preview.1" -Method Get -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")))}

# Output pipelines information
$pipelines
```

**Output: -**

[image]

You can check the **queueStatus** by calling the Get Definitons API from ***above*** ***Definiton API reference link*** [***Get***]:-

**Powershell code: -**

```
$PAT = "hxxxxxxxxwa4gzoia"
$Organization = "sid24desai0738"
$Project = "AzureDevops"
$ApiVersion = "7.1-preview.7"

# Construct the URI
$Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$Organization/$Project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=$ApiVersion"

# Make the GET request to retrieve build definitions
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Uri -Method Get -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT"))
}

# Output the response
$response.value
```

**Output:-**

[image]

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed. I ended up using the update option. Thank you.